# JQuery DatePicker Year dropdownlist disappears in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to maintain the selected date when the user changes the month/year on the JQuery UI Datepicker.  Here's my code:

```
    $("input[class='datePicker hasDatepicker']").each(function (index) {

         $(this).datepicker("option", "onChangeMonthYear",
            function (year, month, inst) {
                var currDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");

                if (currDate)
                    $(this).datepicker("setDate", month + "/" + currDate.getDate() + "/" + year);
          });
    });
```

The code works fine in IE and Chrome, but the dropdownlist for the year disappears in Firefox after you select a date and try to change the month/year.  Any ideas??? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

It looks like the error is directly related to the "setDate" method I'm calling. If you comment it out, there isn't a problem.

Comment: Are you sure about: "input[class='datePicker hasDatepicker']" Usually datePicker is the id and not the class.

Comment: This is the correct selector, it returns the appropriate input and I am able to modify other aspects of the datepicker.

Comment: Try specifying the dateFormat parameter for the datepicker.

I was able to run your code (with different selector) just fine.

Comment: I have had no luck with changing the date format: FireFox just doesn't like it when I try to set the date.  What code did you use to change the format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was something I should have checked right away.  I was using version **[jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI)** and when I updated to the latest version **[jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jqueryUI)** it works fine.